# Electrical cut off switch

Tags: electrical

Every time a regular house light is turned on, I want it to turn off after five or ten minutes. What available options are there in the market for a situation like this? What options are there in the market for a case like this? Something like a garage door opener switch.

Comment: do you want it on timer or on remote

Comment: You may be able to use a timer switch https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/categories/building-materials/electrical/dimmers-switches-and-outlets/timer-switches.html

Comment: Occupancy sensors! You surely don't want the light turning off whilst someone's in the room in need of it, just because of an arbitrary time limit.

Comment: Timer switches in various and variable values are common items, whether old-fashioned reliable clockwork devices or new-fangled electronical ones. Occupancy sensors might, indeed, be a better choice, but timers are easy to find. Really doesn't appear that you actually looked for them before asking...

Comment: @asinine I need a timer but not with a round clock shape thing, just a touch or push switch.

Comment: Why not go to the Smart Home world, timer is old fashion so are the motion sensors. Visit smart home device and you will love it. Once you start you can not stop. Plain timer will anger you going off when it should stay on.

Comment: I'm with @asinine on this, there's no comparison in terms of features like custom timeout periods per light, easy over-rides, single-trigger multiple outputs, custom sensors like radar and beam-break, dim-to-bright activation instead of off-on, you dream it and it's possible with commodity "IoT" gear.

Comment: Do you want the light to turn off after X minutes even if the room is still occupied?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you truly have an "always x minutes" situation, what you probably want is an occupancy sensor or motion detector (they are similar, but not *exactly* the same) with a time delay. The good ones can be programmed in various ways, including:

- Press switch to turn *on* immediately - in case the motion/occupancy isn't detected
- Press switch to turn *off* immediately. This is often configurable, because some places you really want that and some places you don't.
- Selectable delay after "last motion" before turning off automatically. So that if you are in the bathroom and things take a while the light won't show off too quickly.

For example, this [Lutron Maestro from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Maestro-Motion-Sensor-Switch-2-Amp-Single-Pole-White-MS-OPS2H-WH-MS-OPS2H-WH/203202128):

[image: Lutron switch]

- Can install using ground or neutral - very useful if you are replacing an old no-neutral switch loop switch.
- Programmable time-out of lights - set to turn off 1, 5, 15 or 30 minutes after leaving a room.
- Modes include:

  - Auto-ON / Auto-OFF - i.e., full motion sensing
  - Manual-ON / Auto-OFF - press switch to turn on but turns off automatically
  - Manual-ON / Auto-OFF vacancy mode - press switch to turn off, turns off automatically but *also* turns back on automatically if it senses motion (even though after a time delay it will just stay off instead) so you don't get accidentally left in the dark

There are plenty of other brands and models available.

Comment: While they work great in transitory rooms like halls, garages, closets, and laundry, I can't stand PIR-based occupancy sensors for rooms that get actually occupied, like TV/Family, bedroom, etc. As soon as you get into a good book or show the lights turn off on you. You also won't be in the habit of pressing the button, so it's cognitive load nobody needs. I moved to HLK-LD2410-based human sensors that detect heatbeats (omg, they are great), but I don't think there's any commercial offerings of these yet.

Comment: Please post the link from where you copied the instructions

Comment: @asinine The link I included at Home Depot has installation instructions linked on that page.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact found it

Answer (score 1):

This is the traditional type of timer switch used in the UK in communal areas in shared buildings - a pneumatic timer. Push to switch on, it switches off after some minutes, time adjustable internally. There is no override to switch it off early, you have to wait for it to time out.

[image]

Example - https://www.screwfix.com/p/elkay-400a-pneumatic-time-delay-switch/68088

These days, a motion sensor would be a better solution.